# Access parent class property in an inner class instance

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, nested, inner-classes

I want to define a class in JavaScript (TypeScript) that one of its properties (`indentListView`) is an instance of an external class. For defining the inner class instance, I want to access the outer class property (`Selector.modalPanel`). How can I do this?

```js
export class Selector {
    indentListView  // the inner class instance
    modalPanel // the property I wanna access

    constructor(SelectorItems) {

        this.indentListView = new SelectListView({

            didCancelSelection() {
                Selector.modalPanel.hide()   // using `this` here refers to SelectListView instead of Selector 
                return {}
            },

        })

        this.modalPanel = atom.workspace.addModalPanel({
            item: this.indentListView
        })
    }
}
```

I cannot use `this` when I am initiating the inner class because of scoping issues.

Comment: You *can* use `this`, you just need to fix the scoping there - use an arrow function instead of a method

Comment: The question you give me is for a function. I am talking about classes and initiating inner class. I cannot use arrow functions. Please open the question

Comment: Your `didCancelSelection() {` is a method, which is the same as a function in all respects that matter here. The method described in the linked question and in my comment above *will* fix the problem. If you aren't allowed to use an arrow function for some strange reason, you can use `.bind`, or `that = this` - see the linked question

Comment: (`Selector.modalPanel.hide()` doesn't work because `modalPanel` is a property of the instance, not a property of the constructor)

Comment: How can I define `didCancelSelection` using arrow functions? I am allowed, but I don't see the way to do that.

Comment: You defined `didCancelSelection() {` using method syntax - you just need to use an arrow function instead, and then referencing `this` will work as you want it to

Comment: using `   didCancelSelection = () => {
                    this.modalPanel.hide()
                    return {}
                },` breaks my script totally

Comment: You need to use colons to separate a key from a property value, not `=`s - eg `{ foo: 'bar' }`, not `{ foo = 'bar' }`